# Unable to run java-memobile emulator on windows xp

Tags: java, java-me

I downloaded `'Java me sdk 3.0'` recently and `'JDK 7u39'`, i installed it without been prompted with any error. But when i try running one of my java me code, the mobile emulator refuse to start and this is on 'windows xp' though standard java code run perhaps because it doesn't require the mobile emulator. How can i solve this?

Comment: Is there any error message?

Comment: No i didn't get any error, the emulator window just refuse to show up.